# C++ min/max function error (C2665)

Tags: c++, pointers, cin

I'm trying to get this function which takes an int between a min and max range to work properly, but I keep getting the error:

```
No instance of overloaded function "input" matches the argument list
argument types are: (const char [##], int, int)
```

The function that I try  to get working is the following

```
int input(char* t, int min, int max) {
    int number;
    do {
        cout << '\t' << t << " (" << min << '-' << max << "):  ";
        cin >> number;
        cin.ignore();
    } while (number < min || number > max);
    return number;
}
```

To explain a little better.
The `t` argument is basically the question asked, example: "How old are you".
The there is `min` and `max` which are both integers.

Example usage:

```
int years;
years = input("How old are you", 0, 110);
```

And yea, the pointer is supposed to be in the function arguments.

Build errors I get: C2665

Thanks in advance if anyone has the time to help me out.
(all libraries needed are included)

Comment: Change the parameter type to `const char* t`.

Comment: If you read the error, there's your answer. `const char *` is not the same as `char *`.

Comment: Damn.. sorry. Didn't catch that.. Thanks again!

Comment: Mh, the message also says which is the problematic parameter. Don't drop this info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const char*` is not the same as `char*` (String literals are immutable in C++). Change the function signature to:

```
int input(const char* t, int min, int max)
```

Better yet, consider using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).